# how to modify query expression for flexible results - Win Forms C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access, query-expressions

**Introduction**

I am working with winforms.The query expression i have created to search on user input, return results correctly.

**Query Expression**

```
public static readonly string SqlSearchPlotByName = "Select " +
" PropertyId, Contact, Location, Street, Status, City, CreatedDate, Demand, Phase, Area, Corner,Commercial,CompanyName,OwnerName,OwnerAddress,OwnerPhone,Email,Web" +
" From Property Where OwnerName LIKE @OwnerName";
```

**Sql Command Parameters**

```
// name is user input
  dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerName", name);
```

**Problem**

I am having problem to modify the query expression for flexible results.

> For example : when search "jo", the result must be including joe, john, johnny
>   etc.

Can someone please help me modify the query, or any reference/help?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerName", name); use it like dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerName", name+"%");

Comment: great, thanks for the help...please post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerName", name);
```

use it like

```
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerName", name+"%");
```